# How do I implement a lock system for the abap persistency service?

Tags: persistence, abap

I read somewhere that there is no lock system included yet. This info was dated 2009, six years ago. Has that been implemented? Or how can I now implement a lock system?

How can I enshure that between my select and my update anybody else makes changes? I do not want to lock the system after calling a getter, that blocks the entire System..

Comment: I've answered the first question - the rest of your question is - IMHO - way too broad to be answered in the Q&A format of SO

Answer (score 1):

Application-level locking is still not included (and for a good reason - you usually need to lock complex business objects and not the individual entities they consist of). Just use the enqueue objects like in any other ABAP application (and preferably encapsulate them).